# How can I have a footnote with an \url in a section title?

Tags: sectioning, footnotes, urls

When I have a footnote with an `\url` in the section-header, the table of contents shows nothing with it. Why and how can I fix the issue?

Comment: Please add a short example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's in general a bad idea to footnote section titles. The footnote can go, if really necessary, to the first paragraph.

In case you can't get without it, you have to use the optional argument:

```
\section[Section title]{Section title\footnote{A footnote}}
```

otherwise you'll footnote also the table of contents and the headers, which is wrong (and with a `\url` command you'll get many errors).

If the URL contains special characters, LaTeX would have a very hard job, so you should consider the `\urldef` command.

Answer (score 5):

Use like this:

```
\section{Section title\protect\footnote{A footnote}}
```

Comment: ...does not work, even more errors -1 unless clarified.

Comment: It does work for me, but egreg's solution seems to be better. See this similar question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153329/footnote-in-sub-section-title

Comment: @hhh It works for me (+1) in a quite large  document with lots of packages, bibliography, complicated tikz drawings, and extra commands. May be you should revise the spelling; in the beginning I had a spelling error in `\protect`, and because of that I got more errors.