# Footnote in sub-section title

Tags: sectioning, footnotes, koma-script

Trying to put a footnote in subsection title:

```
\subsection{Effect of Lateral Confinement on SW Band Structure\footnote{Parts of this sub--section are based on \citet{Venkat2013}}}
```

produces the following error:

```
Argument of \@sect has an extra } ...section are based on \citet{Venkat2013}}}
```

I am using:

```
 \documentclass[paper=A4, fontsize=12, toc=listof, toc=index, toc=bib]{scrreprt}
```

Please advise.

Comment: related: [Is there a reliable footnote command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3028/579)

Comment: It is also OK, to give that footnote after the first sentence of that subsection.  Footnotes in titles are sometimes unavoidable, but if they are avoidable, I think it is often better to avoid them.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

`\footnote` is a fragile command and section (or subsection) titles are moving arguments (meaning they get written to an auxiliary file to be used in the table of contents). Fragile commands break in moving arguments and the standard solution is to protect them with `\protect`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\begin{document}
\section{foo\protect\footnote{bar}}
\end{document}
```

This will however also produce a footnote in the table of contents:

```
\documentclass[paper=10cm:6cm]{scrartcl}% to get a small picture for tex.sx
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{foo\protect\footnote{bar}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to avoid this use the optional argument of `\section` for the TOC or even better: *don't use footnotes in headings*.

```
\documentclass[paper=10cm:6cm]{scrartcl}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section[foo]{foo\footnote{bar}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yesterday I found, the approach of your answer, which I made a note for, would go terribly wrong in AMS classes, see Barbara Beetons first paragraph here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123763/9237. Lucky, we are using KOMA-Script, where we can control this behaviour, as we want it to do, with these 3 options “headings=optionto…” (or leave in the traditional way).

Comment: @Speravir That's why the real answer is: don't use footnotes in headings. And that's why questions need an MWE...

Comment: I disagree. Sometimes I want to do what I shouldn't and LaTeX shouldn't punish typographical dissidence when I do!

Comment: @cfr but it doesn't: it gives you the tools to achieve them, anyway! :)

Comment: @clemens I was disagreeing with the comment - not the answer!

Comment: @cfr I got that. IMHO LaTeX *doesn't* punish you for “typographical dissidence” but most times gives you the tools to do so… (typographical) rules are there to be broken! In the case at hand one could of course argue that `\footnote` should be robust in the first place, but…

Comment: @clemens It was only a joke. But I do think `\footnote` should behave better, yes.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I would like to add that the `\protect` solution also causes footnotes to appear in page headers (and not only in the TOC). Fortunately, using the optional argument of `\section` as a solution also solves this.

Answer (score 21):

I think "don't do that" is not a helpful answer. Section footnotes are often very useful!

According to: http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-ftnsect.html

The correct thing to do is the following:

```
% in the document preamble
\usepackage[stable]{footmisc}
...
% in the body of the document
\section{title\footnote{title ftnt}}
```

Works great for me.

Comment: `footmisc` works nicely ... but not when there is a `\url{}` in the footnote---which works in other footnotes.

Comment: But it works fine with `\section{title\footnotemark}` and `\footnotetext{\url{}}`. Why didn't I think of it right away? :-((

Comment: Note: footmisc does also change the formatting of footnotes. So if you still want the formatting of the KOMA-Script class you have to repeat the `\deffootnote` command from the KOMA-Script manual after loading `footmisc`.