# scrbook with amsbook style header/footer

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrbook

I am using `scrbook`. I like the look of the running heads and page numbering of `amsbook`. Is there a way to get the same style with `scrbook`?

I already tried:

```
\setkomafont{pagehead}{\normalfont\normalcolor\sc\smaller}
```

MWE for `amsbook`:

```
\documentclass[]{amsbook}

%opening
\title{A Title}
\author{Joe Miller}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: And also a Minimum Working Example of your current code, showing what you've tried. EDIT: Note this comment was initially *after* Speravir's!

Comment: Would be nice, if you’d post an example image of, what you want to have. (Remark: I deleted my first comment for a rewrite after grace period.)

Comment: `\smaller` does only work with package `relsize` and `\sc` is an obsolete command, see for instance in `l2tabu.pdf` (or the version for your native language) in your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 4):

Want you want, can be achieved with one of usual packages for headers and footers. I decided for this one, which is shipped out with KOMA-Script and does, of course, integrate best into the KOMA-Script class `scrbook`. It is **`scrlayer-scrpage`** (could be by the way also used *with other classes not part of KOMA-Script*).

*NOTE: My example does only work from the recently published version 3.12 of KOMA-Script on. Perhaps you must update your TeX distribution first.*

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[markcase=upper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
  \pagestyle{scrheadings}
  \clearpairofpagestyles
  \ohead[]{\pagemark}
  \cfoot[\pagemark]{}
  \chead[]{\headmark}
  \setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scriptsize}% or "\footnotesize" depending on fonts
  \automark[chapter]{chapter}
  \automark*[section]{}

\usepackage[english]{babel}% added for "blindtext", but useful anyway

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\title{A Title}
\author{Joe Miller}

\maketitle

\chapter{From Aa to Zz}
\Blindtext[15]

\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

For description of commands and possibilities of more fine tuning see documentation of `scrlayer-scrpage` (chapter 6 in recent KOMA-Script manual). The command

```
\chead[]{\headmark}
```

acts as if I had written

```
\cehead[]{\leftmark}
\cohead[]{\rightmark}
```

I also intentionally added a chapter without a section.

You should know, that the use of uppercase letters in headings is typographically questionable. I strongly recommend you to read, what Markus Kohm wrote regarding this in the documentation in the section of the package option `markcase`. *(For reasons of AMS decision read [Barbara Beeton’s comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153723/#comment351406_153732) below, and [the addition](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/153723/153732/#comment351525_153732).)*

For small caps instead of full uppercase letters (typographically better, but kerning issues are in most fonts still visible for experienced readers) use this (only changed lines):

```
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
  \setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scriptsize\scshape}
```

The *class* option `numbers=enddot` lets appear dots after numbers.

When one uses the *class* option `chapterprefix=true` (on/yes), but do not want the prefix in headers, and also if one wants a dot after numbers in headers, but not in titlings, the command `\chaptermarkformat` must be redefined:

```
% Remove the chapter prefix:
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\thechapter\autodot\enskip}

% Enforce additionally a dot after numbers in headers:
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{\thechapter.\enskip}
```

Comment: Yes, I will change uppercase to small caps. Is that more acceptable?

Comment: @CraigPr It’s your own decision. But normal case is typographically much, much better (but I did not test with `\scshape`). BTW Maybe instead of `\scriptsize` you want to use `\footnotesize` or `\small`, try it out. If you want dots after the numbers, add a comment (and for definition there’s a difference, whether dots only in heads or also in sectioning titles).

Comment: @Speravir -- although uppercase is indeed typographically inferior to small caps for running heads, unless you can convince authors never to put math expressions into titles and section headings, there is no way to avoid it in the ams document classes.  the decision to use uppercase was made only after very long and intense consideration.

Comment: @Speravir: Thank you. I use the option `chapterprefix=on`. Is it possible to get rid off the word "chapter" in the header and dots after the number?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for this info. I had no intention to be offensive against AMS (though one could think, cf. also [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153329/footnote-in-sub-section-title/153340#comment350896_153340) ;-) ). I‘m sure, you in the AMS have much more clue about typography than amateur people like me.

Comment: @Speravir -- no offense taken.  it's a problem that most people wouldn't even think of; it just becomes glaringly obvious the first time you see what would otherwise be an exemplary small caps running head with `\partial` or `\delta` in it, like a cobra's head sticking up out of a basket.

Comment: @CraigPr With my example code you don’t get dots after the numbers. Or did you mean, you wanted to have dots after them? See answer update – also because of `chapterprefix`.