# Dagger footnote

Tags: sectioning, symbols, footnotes

I would like to add a dagger symbol to one of my section headings that is actually a footnote, so that I can write a comment in the footer. Does anyone know how to change the footnote number to a dagger and then fix it to the section. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/826/symbols-instead-of-numbers-as-footnote-markers

Comment: I think the central part of this question about the footnote being in the section heading: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153329/footnote-in-sub-section-title

Answer (score 6):

Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) next time you ask a question...

I hope this is what you are looking for. Here I define a new command `\daggerfootnote` to be used in such cases. It doesn't interfere with other footnotes numbering, as you can see.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{daggerfootnote}
\newcommand*{\daggerfootnote}[1]{%
    \setcounter{daggerfootnote}{\value{footnote}}%
    \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
    \footnote[2]{#1}%
    \setcounter{footnote}{\value{daggerfootnote}}%
    \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}%
    }

\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill} % just to show the footnotes, don't use it in your document

\section{First section}
bla\footnote{normal footnote.} bla\footnote{normal footnote.}

\section[Section with footnote]{Section with footnote\protect\daggerfootnote{dagger footnote.}}
bla\footnote{normal footnote.} bla\footnote{normal footnote.}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]