# Runaway error in section title

Tags: sectioning, footnotes

I'm using overleaf and getting errors while trying to run

```
\subsection{Decomposition of circular functions as a product of elemental trigonometric functions \footnote{We take elemental trigonometric functions to mean circular functions having a period of $2 \pi$ (i.e. $\sin x$, $\cos x$).}}
```

The error im getting is:

```
Argument of \@sect has an extra }.

<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.24 ...od of $2 \pi$ (i.e. $\sin x$, $\cos x$).}}

I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
 main.tex, line 24

Runaway argument?

{\normalfont \large \bfseries }{\@xfootnote }\def \reserved@b {\stepcounter \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@sect was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.24 ...od of $2 \pi$ (i.e. $\sin x$, $\cos x$).}}

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

Comment: Try with `\subsection[<ToC entry>]{<regular title>}`; the issue is probably related to using a fragile argument (something like `\footnote`) inside the sectional title...

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  As @Werner says, this is probably related to `\footnote`.  In addition to providing the optional <TOC entry> (you really don't want a footnote marker in the TOC), you might need to add `\protect` just before `\footnote`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Footnote in sub-section title](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153329/footnote-in-sub-section-title)

Comment: I have put the \protect command before \footnote and everything seems to work just fine.  Thanks for the answers

Comment: please paste the entire page.