# How to add a footnote to an \addsec in KOMA Script?

Tags: sectioning, footnotes, koma-script

I'm working on a document that uses the `scrbook` class and requires unnumbered chapters and sections that I've solved using `\addchap` and `\addsec` commands respectively and it works fine.

However in one of these unnumbered sections I need to add a footnote, which has not worked for me and I would like to know how to solve that problem.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\extratitle{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\titlehead{consectetur}
\subject{adipisicing}
\title{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\subtitle{consectetur adipisicing elit}
\author{sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua}
\date{}
\publishers{Listopad}
\uppertitleback{
Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo    consequat. 
}
\lowertitleback{
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\addchap{Introduction}

\blindtext[3]

\addsec{A section}%\footnote{This is a footnote for this section.}

\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

If I try to add the footnote inside the section, something like this:

```
\addsec{A section\footnote{This is a footnote for this section.}}
```

I get a compilation error, but if I leave the footnote out, something like this:

```
\addsec{A section}~\footnote{This is a footnote for this section.}
```

but the footnote is loose and not related to the section. How can this be solved?

Comment: Use the optional argument of addsec to avoid that the footnote tries to wander in the table of contents.

Comment: The answer is the same as the one here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/153329/ IMHO, this is a duplicate question

Comment: I agree, you can close it and mark it as a duplicate.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It seems so, thank you very much.