# Adding a footnote in a section title slide in beamer

Tags: beamer, footnotes, section-titles

I would like to add an individual footnote in the title pages generated foreach section.

[image]

I am sharing a minimal working example below.

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer} 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle]{miniframes}
\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=red}

\setbeamercolor{section page}{fg=black, bg= darkred!50}
\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
    \vfill
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{section page}
        \usebeamerfont{title}%
        \textit{Section \thesection~}%
                {\color{black} \insertsectionhead}\par%
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vfill
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
\section{My section}
\begin{frame}{My slide}
    Some text here. 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I have tried the following trick, but it did not work.

```
\section[My section]{My section\raisebox{.3\baselineskip}{\normalsize\footnotemark}}\footnotetext{Here is my note}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  `\protect\footnote{...}`

From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153340/161015

> `\footnote` is a fragile command and section (or subsection) titles
> are moving arguments (meaning they get written to an auxiliary file to
> be used in the table of contents). Fragile commands break in moving
> arguments and the standard solution is to protect them with `\protect`

[image: z]

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer} 
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\useoutertheme[footline=authortitle]{miniframes}
\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=red}

\setbeamercolor{section page}{fg=black, bg= darkred!50}
\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}
        \vfill
        \centering
        \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=12pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{section page}
            \usebeamerfont{title}%
            \textit{Section \thesection~}%
            {\color{black} \insertsectionhead\protect\footnote{bar}}\par% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \end{beamercolorbox}
        \vfill
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}
    \section{My section}
    \begin{frame}{My slide}
        Some text here. 
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Adding `\renewcommand\footnoterule{}` in the preamble will remove the red separation rule.